# How to declare the index of an array from a global variable

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables, extern

How do I get the index of an array which will take the the value of a global variable declared elsewhere.

```
//inside stress.h
#include "note.h"

extern int nelement = Element; //int Element is a global variable declared inside note.h
#define nmesh 10

int array [nelement*nmesh]; //error: expression must have a constant value
```

`Element` is a variable which will be read during run-time.

Comment: Can I have some more sources or keywords to look at? And how do I get this work?

Comment: 1) Don't use global variables like this. Overall, the presence of the `extern` keyword is generally a clear indication of bad program design. 2) You can't set an array size based on a run-time constant unless the array is declared in local scope.